# Azure: Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase

Tags: azure-sql-database

We got the error below hundreds of time this morning:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection Timeout Expired.  The   timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase.  The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=1; handshake=14; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=0; [Post-Login] complete=14008;  ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByte(Byte& value)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
```

How come we got timeouts? We get this error event when we connect using Management Studio and it's often really slow.

The default SQL timeout is 15 seconds. Should we set it to 120 seconds? IT looks to me like a performance issue in Azure.

Any thought?

Thanks,

Stéphane

Comment: did you every find out why?

Comment: Is this just during login?